# Can not add and remove JComponents in Java ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I coded a Login window. When user enter username and password in text fields and hit the Login button, i send username and password to a server for authentication. Server simply return "false", if not authenticated.

I want to add New JLabel with splash icon in JPanel and remove old jlabel OR change old JLabel text and add an image init, during HTTP request and response. When response came back, i hide this Login window and open new one.

But issue is this, In ActionListener method, whenever i remove and add JLabel from/to panel, it did not work.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // remove error label and add processing label
            panel.remove(errorLable);

            processingLabel.setIcon(processingIcon);
            panel.add(processingLabel);
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();
```

As i did lot of time this work, But not work this time. I wondered...
When Server send "false" response, then this piece of code works. Otherwise not.

Here is complete code of this class.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class LoginWindow extends JFrame {

public JFrame frame;
private JTextField txtUsername;
private JPasswordField txtPassword;
private JLabel errorLable;
public String name;
private JLabel lblPassword;
public JPanel panel;

public LoginWindow() {

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 341, 367);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setTitle("Test");
    //frame.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

    panel = new JPanel();
    //panel.setBounds(new Rectangle(9, 11, 500, 254));
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel.setBorder(null);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    centerPanel.setBorder(null);
    frame.getContentPane().add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    centerPanel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username");
    usernameLabel.setBounds(86, 88, 92, 14);
    centerPanel.add(usernameLabel);

    txtUsername = new JTextField();
    txtUsername.setBounds(86, 102, 166, 30);
    txtUsername.setText("qaisar");
    centerPanel.add(txtUsername);
    txtUsername.setColumns(10);

    lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
    lblPassword.setBounds(86, 158, 92, 14);
    centerPanel.add(lblPassword);

    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    loginButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    loginButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    loginButton.setBounds(86, 237, 166, 30);
    centerPanel.add(loginButton);

    txtPassword = new JPasswordField();
    txtPassword.setText("aA123456");
    txtPassword.setBounds(86, 172, 166, 30);
    centerPanel.add(txtPassword);
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

    errorLable = new JLabel("Enter login details");
    errorLable.setOpaque(true);
    errorLable.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    errorLable.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    panel.add(errorLable);

    JLabel processingLabel = new JLabel("Proccessing....");


    URL urlProcessing = LoginFrame.class.getResource("/resources/processing.png");
    ImageIcon processingIcon = new ImageIcon(urlProcessing);


    // Define an action for Login Button and password text fields
    Action action = new AbstractAction(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // remove error label and add processing label
            panel.remove(errorLable);

            processingLabel.setIcon(processingIcon);
            panel.add(processingLabel);
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();

            //frame.add
            String username = txtUsername.getText();
            name = username;
            char[] password = txtPassword.getPassword();
            JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();

            try {
                jsonParams.put("username", username);
                jsonParams.put("password", String.valueOf(password));
                String url="http://localhost:8080/turnle/frontend/web/api/user/login";
                String response = null;

                response = Login(jsonParams, url);

                    if (response.equals("false")) {
                        errorLable.setText("Username or passwrod is incorrect!");                           
                    } else {
                        // processing response etc...
                        // Hide this window ...
                        // opend new one....
                    }                        

            } catch (IOException | JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        };
    };
    // add action to login button
    loginButton.addActionListener(action);

}

public String Login(JSONObject jsonParams, String url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException, JSONException{

    URL object=new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    OutputStreamWriter wr= new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(jsonParams.toString());
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();  
    int HttpResult = con.getResponseCode(); 
    if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
        String line = null;  
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
            response.append(line + "\n");  
        }
        br.close();  
    } else {
        String falseResponse = "false";
        return falseResponse;
    }  
    return response.toString();
 }
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Major error: your code is doing long-running processing on the Swing event thread, rendering it completely useless. Any changes to the state of the GUI immediately and before this process will not be shown. Please Google and read the "Concurrency in Swing" tutorial, and then create and use a SwingWorker to help you do this without suppressing the event thread.

Comment: Minor issues: `setLayout(null);` and `setBounds(...)` leads to terrible GUI's, ones that are very difficult to maintain and enhance. Learn and use the layout managers.

Comment: *"Here is complete code of this class."* In future, post a [mcve] & make sure that custom 3rd part classes like `org.json.JSONObject` are factored out.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I tried SwingWorker as well, but not succeeded. I moved all the Login class code to SwingWorker Inner class and called it from Login Constructor. Second: I moved ActionListener to SwingWorker, But this did not worked as well. Any Idea how to implement SwingWorker ? should i past swingworker code as well ?

Comment: `"I moved all the Login class code to SwingWorker Inner class..."` -- this doesn't sound good. Only the background thread / long-running process code goes here. Don't just use a SwingWorker, but read its tutorial first as well. If stuck, then you'll need to ask a question with your SwingWorker [mcve] code.

Comment: Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels got solution by using SwingUtilities.invokeLater